# Would questions about the latest episode of The Flash be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Remember a few years back, when Jeff used the notion of [a fight between a gorilla and a shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) as the archetypal example of a question that's off-topic on StackExchange?  Well, guess what happened in the most recent *The Flash* episode, *King Shark vs Gorilla Grodd*?

I just can't help but wonder, is that still off-topic now?

Comment: SFF's policy on so-called "gorilla vs shark" questions [may be found here](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/). Regardless of what Mr Atwood said in 2011, the key issue for us is "*Can we answer this question objectively, based solely on in-canon information?*", or even "*Has this fight/race/confrontation/etc actually happened, and what was the outcome?*"

Comment: @Randal'Thor -  I presume this question was intended as a funny

Comment: @Valorum [Correct](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49334934#49334934): _"yes, but it's still amusing to find something that so perfectly pokes fun at one of our long-standing community norms"_